# What are some good apps for screensharing/recording video games?

Tags: windows, streaming, video-recording, windows-11, performance

I want to screenshare or record video games (such as VALORANT, The Finals, and other taxing-ish games) where recording or screen-sharing (with at least one other person watching) my screen won't impact my fps, speed, etc. Remember, these games are online, so performance dips are very bad.

This is on a PC. Windows-11 OS. The software should be able to record or share my voice as well as in-game sounds.

Just to clarify, I'm not trying to post this on a social media app (and they should not be recommended as answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) is the go-to open source video recording and broadcasting software.

While screen recording is generally a resource intensive task, and recording without any performance impact is generally considered unattainable, OBS Studio is specifically made for live streaming and recording games and other activities, and strives to be as lightweight and non-intrusive as possible.